# PHP: Problems reading and write back to file

Tags: php, json, file

```
$fh = fopen(PATH_TO_FILE, "r+");
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
$data = fgets($fh);
$data = json_decode($data, true);

$data['mod_1'] = 1;

$data_write = json_encode($data);
ftruncate($fh, 0);
fwrite($fh , $data_write);
clearstatcache();
flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fh);
```

This works only if I prepare JSON file by myself. The problem is, next time I try to call this method, `json_decode()` returns false and the file is partial corrupted. `json_decode()` can not parse it anymore.

What is the problem with this code?

My JSON File contents:

```
{"mod_1":0,"mod_2": 0}
```

All I want is to read file, modify its content and write back to file(overwrite). I must use `LOCK_EX`, so I assume `file_put_contents` is not for me.

Comment: _“My JSON File contents:”_ - that is before you tried to modify it, I assume? Have you actually checked what it contains _after_ you did that …? You neglected to rewind the file pointer here, so it should just contain your new, modified JSON _after_ the old, already existing one.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which should include a before and after sample of the json, in this case.

Comment: Before reading JSON file, bash command "file -bi  myfile" outputs "application/json; charset=us-ascii". Right after "fwrite($fh , $data_write);" "file -bi myfile" outputs "application/octet-stream; charset=binary". I assume this is the root of my problem ho can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that ftruncate didn't set the pointer at the beginning of empty file. So I added rewind($fh) right after ftruncate and the problem was solved.